# problems with unit test nestjs using Firebase Functions locally

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-functions, nestjs-config, nestjs-jwt

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sS8z.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJNjz.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkoTq.jpg)
Hello, good evening, could you please help me with a unit test I am doing in NestJS using Firebase Functions locally?

I have been reading the firestore documentation but have not been able to solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.